# HermesJMS showing error :javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Could not load resource:

Tags: java, ssl, jms, activemq-classic, soapui

I am unable to configure org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory in 
HermesJMS.It ends up saying an error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not load resource: D:\ActiveMQCertificates\broker.ks
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.getUrlOrResourceAsStream(ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.loadClientCredential(ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.java:158)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.createKeyManager(ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory.java:105)
    ... 51 more
```

I have the keystore file at D:\ActiveMQCertificates\broker.ks .But the hermes is unable to load the resource.

The config in Hermes is

brokerURL  : ssl://localhost:61616
keyStore        : D:\ActiveMQCertificates\broker.ks
KeystorePaswword :xxxxx

How to specify the keystore path in Hermes?
Help me in this.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: Did you connect to ActiveMQ(without hermes) successfully?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.activemq.user/36094), try to adding it in JAVA_OPTS

```java
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the connection factory doesn't know how to handle simple file name. Try creating a new file with the String, then convert the URi to string and pass that as parameter. Found [solution here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwishdih4PLMAhXLPz4KHdH_BAkQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmail-archives.apache.org%2Fmod_mbox%2Factivemq-users%2F201212.mbox%2F%253C1355338829.83889.YahooMailNeo%40web160402.mail.bf1.yahoo.com%253E&usg=AFQjCNFeB4Z-tXzzuo68sPfTHTIT7Jds6Q&sig2=oq6SoHLem4URJkOlCvx1AA).E.g.:

```
connectionFactory.setTrustStore(new File("/path/to/store").toURI().toString());
```